# Illegal Assignment from List to List with Lookup Field

Tags: apex

I have the following code in my class that is getting the error. The field Student__c is a lookup field to the Contact object. Any ideas why I am getting this error?

```
List<Contact> Contacts = [Select Student__c From Stage_History__c Where Stage__c = 'Stage1'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will return a `List<Stage_History__c>` records and thus your current assignment to `List<Contact>` is an illegal assignment.

Depending on your use case, you will need to fetch the `Contacts` from the returned list.

Simplest way would be to utilize as:

```
List<Contact> retList = [SELECT <contact fields> 
                         FROM CONTACT 
                         WHERE Id IN 
                           (Select Student__c 
                            From Stage_History__c Where Stage__c = 'Stage1')
                        ];
```

OR

Iterate over the `List<Stage_History__c>` and populate the Contacts.

```
List<Contact> cList = new List<Contact>();
List<Stage_History__c> retList = [Select Student__c From Stage_History__c Where Stage__c = 'Stage1'];

for(Stage_History__c s : retList) {
    cList.add(s.Student__c);
}
```

Comment: Doh, I knew I was missing something easy. Thanks!